# Concatenate rows into a single text string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen similar questions but feel this is not a duplicate question. I would like to concatenate rows into single string with joins. I am confused on how to proceed. Syntax below
I am getting an error "There is already an object named '#TEMPTABLE' in the database." also I am not sure if my sytax to the 2nd select statement is correct, help?

```
SELECT DISTINCT DisplayName, addrSt, addrCntyName,
RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar, addrStFips), 2) + RIGHT('000' + convert(varchar,    addrCntyFips), 3) AS addrFips

INTO #TEMPTABLE

FROM PPP 
  INNER JOIN poa ON PPP.OAJ = poa.OAJ
  INNER JOIN dcPfp ON PfpPayor.KEYF = dbo.dcPfp.KEYJ 
  INNER JOIN ProvOff ON ProvOffAfl.OJK = ProvOff.OJK

SELECT DISTINCT 
 addrFips,
  STUFF
  (
    (
        SELECT ',' + DisplayName
        FROM #TEMPTABLE M
        WHERE M.addrFips = B.addrFips 
        ORDER BY DisplayName
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,''
        ) AS DISPLAYNAMES
FROM #TEMPTABLE B

DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE
```

Comment: Well, your error means that you haven't dropped the `#TEMPTABLE` before running the query again. First execute the `DROP TABLE` and then start from the begining

Comment: Add `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMPTABLE') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Results` before your SQL and try it again :-)

Comment: Extending on bummi's suggestion use batch separator `GO` after you have executed the statement he has suggested.

Comment: Thank you bummi, it works along with the GO statement suggested by M.Ali

Comment: You might answer your own question, if you like to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked in my situation was IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.#TEMPTABLE') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results 
GO

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

The error message `There is already an object named '#TEMPTABLE' in the database.` means that you've created a temporary table with this name in a previous run. To solve this, you need to `DROP` this table or use another name.

To drop, use the following code before your query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMPTABLE') IS NOT NULL 
   DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE
```

Comment: Posting the solution that were added in the comments. Tagging it as community wiki following this recommendation: [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/1476885).

Answer (score 0):

You can use undocumented string concatenation feature.

```
DECLARE @big_string varchar(max) = '';

SELECT @big_string += x.s + ','
FROM (VALUES ('string1'), ('string2'), ('string3')) AS x(s);

SELECT @big_string;

-- OUTPUT:
-- string1,string2,string3,
```

It's that easy. As for order guarantees, read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2005/07/20/ordering-guarantees-in-sql-server/) article.